# How can I translate the English phrase "you need all the X you can get" into German

Tags: translation, english-to-german, idiom

In English, there is a common expression: to "need all the [noun] you can get," which implies that someone is in a bad situation. For example:

> But I lost another $10,000, and now the bank says they are going to take my house if I can't make the payments this month. Do you think I need help?
>
> I think you need all the help you can get!

Does it make sense to translate this word for word into German or is it just an English idiom? Do people say, for example, "er braucht jede Hilfe, die er bekommen kann" in German?

Google Translate says yes, but I am not sure I trust it, as I know it can get some idiomatic things wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

> Er braucht jede Hilfe, die er bekommen kann

we say:

> Er braucht [jetzt] jede erdenkliche Hilfe

Answer (score 4):

"Jede Hilfe, die er bekommen kann" is certainly an acceptable translation. I would understand it that way, and it would not sound odd to my ears at all.

Other possibilities are to replace "jede Hilfe" with "all die Hilfe", or the verb "bekommen" with the more colloquial "kriegen".

Comment: To my native ears this sounds unnatural.